Is there a resolution to the "Wigner's Friend" paradox?
Suppose that two observers $A$ and $B$ are mutually isolated, observer $A$ measures the state $|0\rangle + |1\rangle$ and concludes that the result is $|0\rangle$.
However, observer $B$ concludes that the evolution of the system "state + observer $A$" is always unitary, because of the isolation, thus concluding that the state evolves to $|0\rangle|A_{0}\rangle + |1\rangle|A_{1}\rangle$, which has physically different properties from either $|0\rangle|A_{0}\rangle$ or $|1\rangle|A_{1}\rangle$.
Neither state can be reached via a unitary transformation, thus the conclusion of observer $A$ that the state is $|0\rangle$ is wrong, as this would entail that the state for $B$ is $|0\rangle|A_{0}\rangle$.
It seems that to solve the inconsistency, logically at least one of these conclusions must be true:

The evolution of an isolated system is not unitary
The fact that the state is $|0\rangle$ for $A$ does not entail that the state for $B$ would be $|0\rangle|A_{0}\rangle$

Is there any experimental evidence on which of these conclusion is true? Is there a hidden assumption i'm not considering when reasoning about the argument?

Perhaps Qubism?

What does it mean for two observers to be spacelike separated? How do you know it is the case that "one of them is the correct one, namely the one fixed by A's observation in his laboratory"?

If $A$ is truly isolated from their environment, maybe $|0\rangle |A \rangle_0 + |1 \rangle |A \rangle_1$ really is a valid description of the state. On the other hand, in a realistic setup $A$ is going to interact with, eg, the walls of the lab, and that is going to cause decoherence which would mean in practice it wouldn't be possible for $B$ to perform an interference experiment with the two branches of the wavefunction.

What paradox are you trying to resolve?  You have two different theories that make exactly the same testable predictions.  That happens all the time in physics, and there is nothing paradoxical about it.

"Observers do not have a state in quantum mechanics" seems fine to me. There is no measurement operator after all, so an observer cannot be modeled as such by a quantum state. Either the observer measures, which ends the validity of the state, or the observer does not measure, and then does not qualify as an observer.

If an observer cannot be modeled by quantum mechanics, one would need to formally write the specific observer to which a state is relative to, eg: $|\Psi\rangle_{A}$, which is an absurdity as it would require conscious agency to play a fundamental role in the theory

You provided this bullet point yourself as a way to resolve the paradox you see in Wigner's friend, so I do not understand your objection. The resolution goes that way: once A has measured the state, there is no superposition anymore, even for B. Simple, and no need to include observers either into or relatively to a state - when there is an observation, there is no state anymore.

But of course we are left with the measurement problem.

You can solve the paradox that way, but the cost is that the theory becomes nonsensical, I was therefore wondering if there is an hidden assumption which makes the paradox trivial. Once $A$ has measured the state, his conclusions would be wrong unless states are fundamentally relative to conscious agency, this is simply because $B$'s state is different from whatever $A$ can conclude with a measurement.

Well if bullet 3 is the resolution, then it is $B$'s state that is wrong, precisely because you cannot include an observer in a quantum state.

I agree, yes, however the notion of observer is not mathematically defined, so the expression $|\Psi\rangle_{A}$ doesn't make sense, it is a metaphysical object.

Resolutions are offered by quantum interpretations, of which there are tons. However we cannot on a unique resolution.

@MaximalIdeal We cannot agree because none of them is convincing.

I will try to give an experimentally motivated and pragmatic answer, since there are actually testable predictions one can make that distinguish between different interpretations of the measurement problem.
Objective collapse models would predict that the qubit actually collapses to $|0\rangle$ or $|1\rangle$, in which case your first bullet point "The evolution of an isolated system is not unitary" would be the resolution to the paradox.
Many-worlds posits that the system remains in superposition $|0\rangle|A_0\rangle + |1\rangle|A_1\rangle$. $A$ is in a superposition of having seen $|0\rangle$ and having seen $|1\rangle$. There is no contradiction, because as soon as $B$ asks $A$ what she is seeing, $B$ becomes entangled with the qubit as well:
$$|0\rangle|A_0\rangle|B_0\rangle + |1\rangle|A_1\rangle|B_1\rangle$$
Thus as soon as $B$ observes $A$, $B$ sees only one outcome or the other. This resolution to the paradox doesn't fit into your initial list of possible resolutions. Maybe we can summarize it as "Measurement is observer-dependent" or something like that.
Post script: doing the experiment
Notice that $B$ observing $A$ does nothing to distinguish between many-worlds and objective collapse models. But in principle there is an experiment $B$ can perform to distinguish them. If $A$ and the qubit together constitute a perfectly isolated system, then the act of $A$ performing the measurement can be written as the following unitary:
$$U = |0\rangle\langle 0| U_0 + |1\rangle\langle 1| U_1$$
where $U_0$ and $U_1$ are unitaries that transform $A$'s initial state $|A\rangle$ to the states $|A_0\rangle$ and $|A_1\rangle$ respectively. Now if $A$ performs the measurement, and then $B$ subsequently applies $U^\dagger$, the system reverts to its initial state $(|0\rangle + |1\rangle)|A\rangle$. $B$ can then measure the qubit in the $X$ basis (i.e. $|0\rangle+|1\rangle$ and $|0\rangle - |1\rangle$), and will always observe $|0\rangle+|1\rangle$ as the outcome. We avoid contradiction because in order to restore the superposition, we necessarily erased $A$'s memory of her original measurement outcome!
However in the objective collapse scenario, applying $U^\dagger$ takes the joint system from $|0\rangle|A_0\rangle$ to $|0\rangle|A\rangle$ (or likewise for 1). Now $B$'s final measurement will yield a random outcome ($|0\rangle+|1\rangle$ or $|0\rangle-|1\rangle$ with 50% probability). Repeating the whole experiment many times, $B$ can determine with high confidence if objective collapse is occurring.
In practice, perfectly isolating a human being and applying $U^\dagger$ to her is an impossible task. However there are more modest experiments one can do. Many practical quantum measurements involve relatively simple measurement devices, such as an optical cavity or a vibrating membrane. The larger and more complex the measurement device, the harder it is to isolate the whole system and apply $U^\dagger$, but such experiments have been performed on small scales. See e.g. To catch and reverse a quantum jump mid-flight.

Three observations should be noted.
First, as far as the issue itself goes, it bears pointing out that measurements made at space-like separation are subject to the "microcausality postulate" so that the observables describing them commute or anti-commute ... and don't interfere.
The second is that Wigner-type setups can be used to formulate constraints on what is permitted for quantum theories and their interpretation, with those constraints being stronger than what the Bell Theorem imposes. In particular, there is the "Either Superdeterminism, Non-Locality, Or The Existence Of The Observed Is Not Absolute" no go result A Strong No Go Theorem On Wigner's friend paradox peer-review stamped and ArXiv preprint.
Third, despite the field of classical - quantum hybrid dynamics being a landmine of no-go results, there is That Recently Published framework for classico-quantum hybrid dynamics. Of course, this is referring to Oppenheim. Though originally sold as a mash-up of quantum theory and classical general relativity, what it actually is: is a general framework for classico-quantum hybridization that just happens to have a quantum theory / classical general relativity mash-up as one of its applications and corollaries (and, in fact, does not actually preclude the existence of an actual quantum theory of gravity, by Oppenheim's account).
The underpinning to the Wigner's Friend issue is - and always was - the question of whether, where and how the classicalization associated with measurements takes place at. Are anthropoid observers (when thought of as measuring devices) on the classical side of the divide, if there is a divide? More generally, is there some kind of scale where a transition from quantum'ness and classical'ness exists? That's actually the core issue of Measurement Theory, itself: the two questions of (1) whether classicalization occurs and of (2) where/how it occurs, if so. They can be equivalently stated as (1) whether classico-quantum hybrid dynamics is possible and exists and (2) what can be treated as being on the classical side of the dynamics, if so.
The reason the two characterizations should be thought of as equivalent, is that in any non-trivial hybrid dynamics (i.e. a hybrid dynamics where the quantum subsystem back-reacts to the classical sub-system) the classical sub-system is a de facto measurement device for the quantum subsystem. If you think about it, that's actually the definition of a measurement device, in this context (or at least what people have always wanted out of a measurement device): a classical sub-system that reflects the properties of the quantum sub-system it is interacting with.
As yet, I have not seen Oppenheim or his group apply the new classico-quantum hybrid dynamics framework to the Wigner's friend issue. It would be interesting to see what comes of it, when they (or other interested parties - any takers here?) get around to trying it out.

Wavefunction collapse isn't subjective. It happens or it doesn't. If it happens, then the evolution of a (macroscopic) isolated system isn't unitary. If it doesn't happen, then the A who sees 0 should technically use the full state $|0\rangle|A_{0}\rangle + |1\rangle|A_{1}\rangle$, which also contains the other world whose A saw 1, but since worlds realistically never interfere again after a measurement, $|0\rangle|A_{0}\rangle$ is a reasonable approximation.
Unfortunately, it's practically impossible to distinguish these cases since you'd have to observe interference between worlds (or lack thereof), and worlds realistically don't interfere.

"Wavefunction collapse isn't subjective" is not even wrong; first, you have to argue that there is something like wave function collapse. Also, you seem to argue within the many worlds interpretation, which, however, is just one of many different, equivalent interpretations.

@TobiasFünke OP suggested that wave function collapse might both happen and not happen in the same experiment. I said it either happens or it doesn't happen, not both. I don't need to "argue that there is something like wave function collapse", because if there's no such thing then it doesn't happen, and I covered that case. That case is many-worlds. I also covered the case that it does happen, which is not many-worlds. I didn't spend much time on that one, because it was one of OP's bulleted resolutions ("The evolution of a isolated system is not unitary").

There is a resolution. I wouldn't say it is commonly accepted.
The Copenhagen and statistical interpretations say there is no account of what is happening in reality in quantum mechanical experiments. In such theories, problems like Wigner's friend play the role of a reason to say quantum theory is incomprehensible so there is no reason to try to understand what's happening.
If instead we take quantum equations of motion seriously as a description of reality, then there is a solution. When observer $A$ measures a qubit in the state $|0\rangle+|1\rangle$ he ends up in the state $|0\rangle|A_0\rangle+|1\rangle|A_1\rangle$. A human being is a large system that can't avoid interacting with the environment and copying information to it. Such interactions suppress interference through a process called decoherence
https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06282
https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.2189
As a result each of the states of $|0\rangle|A_0\rangle,|1\rangle|A_1\rangle$ evolve independently of one another to a good approximation. So there will be a version of $A$ that sees $0$ and another that sees $1$ and to a good approximation they won't interfere. This looks a bit like a collection of parallel universes and is commonly called the many worlds interpretation but it is just a consequence of quantum theory without collapse.
If $B$ hasn't interacted with $A$ directly or indirectly then he won't undergo decoherence with respect to those two states and so from his point of view the relative state will be $|0\rangle|A_0\rangle+|1\rangle|A_1\rangle$. There is a description in the Heisenberg picture of how the relative state of a system changes locally as a result of interactions:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.02328
